# transition and target in css

Tags: css, css-transitions

I'm working on creating a page with some CSS-animations (due to some of my customers dont want JavaScript heavy site). So I have one element I want to animate, but in 3 different ways based on which button is clicked:

Example:

```
<a href="#element">One animation</a>
<a href="#element">Second animation</a>
<a href="#element">Third animation</a>

<div id="element"></div>
```

The way I select the element is with :target. But how can I animate the same element in three different ways using :target?

This is the CSS I have by now for testing purposes:

```
#element{
height: 10px;
width: 10px;
border-radius: 0px;
background-color: red;
position: absolute;
left: 440px;
top: 300px;
-webkit-transition-property: height, width, background-color,;
-webkit-transition-duration: 5s;
-webkit-transition-timing-function:ease-out;
}

#element:target{
height: 300px;
width: 500px;
border-radius: 0px;
background-color: blue;
position: absolute;
left: 200px;
top: 200px;
}
```

So I basically want to have 3 different :target styles on the same element. Is this possible?

Answer (score 5):

You can do it by using css `adjacent(+)` selector like this:

**HTML:**

```
<a id='first' href="#first">One animation</a>
<a id='second' href="#second">Second animation</a>
<a id='third' href="#third">Third animation</a>

<div id="element" class="force-repaint"></div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#element{
    height: 300px;
    width: 300px;
    border-radius: 0px;
    background-color: red;
    position: absolute;
    left: 300px;
    top: 50px;
    -webkit-transition-property: height, width, background-color,;
    -webkit-transition-duration: .2s;
    -webkit-transition-timing-function:ease-out;
}

#first:target + #second + #third + #element { 
    background: yellow;
}

#second:target + #third + #element{
    background: green;
}

#third:target + #element{
    background: purple;
}

.force-repaint { -webkit-animation: bugfix infinite 1s; }
@-webkit-keyframes bugfix { from { fill: 0; } to { fill: 0; } }
```

Working **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/eMK8n/2/)**

Comment: +1 It's a shame that a good answer can go so long with 0 points.

Comment: Better way to do the first transition is: `#first:target ~ #element { 
    background: yellow;
}`

Answer (score 0):

> So I basically want to have 3 different :target styles on the same element. Is this possible?

Nope, that’s not possible – not directly.

> But how can I animate the same element in three different ways using :target?

By using three different targets.

You could put the actual element you want to apply the transition on into a number of nested container elements, like so:

```
<div id=target1>
  <div id=target2>
    <div id=target3>
      <element>
```

and then have your three links pointing to one of those target ids each, and use the descendant combinator in CSS to apply the transition you want for each case,

```
#target1 element { … }
#target2 element { … }
#target3 element { … }
```